# In IntelliJ IDEA, how to set default inspection profile for new projects?

Tags: intellij-idea, profile, inspection

I have a custom, IDE-wide profile for Inspections in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm often creating new projects, and I want to use this profile with them by default.

I tried going to `File > Other Settings > Default Settings...` and changing `Editor > Inspections > Profile` to point to my new profile.  But when I create a new project, it is still using the `Project Default` profile.

Is this setting broken? Is my understanding of default project/profile settings not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspections from the profile you select as the default are copied to the project default profile when the new project is created. There is an open issue about that:

- [IDEA-154618](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154618) Inspection Profile Management issues

Your specific problem is described under **ISSUE 5**:

> There doesn't seem to be a way to set a global profile as the default
>   for new projects such that the project continues to use the global
>   default. If on the default settings dialog I set my profile to "My
>   Standard Inspections", when I create a new project, the settings I
>   have in "{idea.home}/inspections/My Standard Inspections.xml" are
>   copied to ".idea/inspections/Project_Default.xml". While I can
>   understand this might be desired behavior for teams that want a
>   standard inspection profile used for a project and for it to be shared
>   via VCS, that is not the case for me (and my co-workers). I want a
>   global profile that all my projects use such that as I tweak my
>   inspection profile over time, all projects use the updated profile (as
>   they are using a common global profile). This is the paradigm I've
>   used since IDEA v3. But it's broken down recently because of the
>   reworking of inspection profile management. While I could go in and
>   change the inspection profile from "Project Default" to "My Standard
>   Inspections" each and every time I create a new project, that is a
>   real pain, and is error prone. I think there needs to be an option to
>   select the behavior for the default profile setting to either "Use as
>   a global profile" or "Copy to project default profile".

We've also created a separate issue for this problem, please follow for updates:

- [IDEA-170928](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170928) Default inspection profile isn't applied for a new project

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. Looking at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170928 it should be fixed in 2017.2 but I just downloaded 2017.2 EAP and I open a new project and my though my profile is on automatically on "default", my annotations are empty. This is for project inspections as well as when I edit default settings inspections. Now when I change my project by opening recent project, and there both project and default annotations are filled. I don't get it, why would my DEFAULT settings even differ, looking at them from 2 different projects? It's the IDE defaults, isn't it? :(